# How to connect multiple databases from different subdomain and make a single select query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible to connect different databases located in different subdomains by using `mysqli_connect`, and then run a single `select` query to get data from all the databases?
Suppose I have two databases located in different sub-domain:

```
$connect1 = mysqli_connect($hostname1, $username1, $password1,$database1); 
$connect2 = mysqli_connect($hostname2, $username2, $password2, $database2);
```

Then I want to select data from the two databases:

```
SELECT `Id` FROM `$database1`.`users` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$string_1%'
UNION ALL
SELECT `Id` FROM `$database2`.`masters` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$string_2%';
```

Here *users* is a database table of `$database1` and *masters* is a table of `$database2`.
But I don't know how to make a single `mysqli_query` with this.

Comment: You can't union across servers unfortunately

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. As you can see for mysqli_connect() method takes exactly four arguments including database name. You cannot include multiple values there. Can I suggest importing the second table to the first database or vice versa.

Comment: *Someone who proposed to have these two tables on different hosts* (and even databases) must be assigned to this task.